# Why I can not use disposable objects in object members?

Tags: .net, f#, idisposable

I don't want to add `StreamWriter` parameter to Write-To-File procedure but when I'm trying to work with disposable StreamWriter there I'm getting:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.
```

code:

```
let fileLogger = {
    new IFlog with
        member i.FLog level format =
            use file = LogFile()
            Printf.kfprintf 
                (fun f -> 
                    fprintfn file "[%s][%A] " 
                            <| level.ToString()
                            <| DateTime.Now
                    ) file (format)
```

so when I call FLog method twice I get this.

I can use it alike this : `member i.FLog file level format` and control disposable object on top level but then I lose all the abstraction.

Is there some way to use disposable objects like that? Or how can I change architecture to avoid passing disposable parameter into this function?

LogFile is :

```
let mutable LogFileName = "F.log"
let LogFile() =
    match File.Exists(LogFileName) with
    | false -> File.CreateText(LogFileName)
    | true  -> File.AppendText(LogFileName)
```

Comment: If you have a logfile why are you disposing at all - just let the object be disposed when the app exits

Comment: the name is mutable and could be changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the exception because the function you pass to `Printf.kfprintf` is compiled as a closure which captures a reference to your `file` variable -- i.e., your `TextWriter` instance. Once `Printf.kfprintf` returns, `file` goes out of scope; the compiler sees that it is not used anywhere else and thus inserts some code to call the `Dispose()` method on the `TextWriter`. By the time you call the closure returned by the `FLog` method, `file` has already been disposed so the exception is raised.

It's a little easier to visualize with some code. This is how the F# compiler compiles the `FLog` method:

```
member i.FLog level format =
    try
        let file = LogFile()
        Printf.kfprintf 
            (fun f -> 
                fprintfn file "[%s][%A] " 
                        <| level.ToString()
                        <| DateTime.Now
                ) file (format)
    finally
        if file <> null then file.Dispose ()
```

You could fix this by having the declaring type of `FLog` implement `IDisposable`, and making the `file` value part of the class instead of declaring it within the method. When the declaring type's `Dispose()` method is called, it should just call `file.Dispose()`. You'll still need to take care not to use any closures you've created with `FLog` after you've disposed the instance though, or you'll end up with the same exception you're seeing now.

Comment: thank you but even adding file to class breaks desired abstraction :S