# Can I use "fuzzy" parameter pass with IDisposable objects?

Tags: syntax, f#, parameter-passing, idisposable

Here is simple snippet I created to understand why I have dispose before action in my code

```
type IType = 
    inherit IDisposable
    abstract say : string -> unit

let St = {
    new IType with
        member i.say hi     = Console.Write hi
        member i.Dispose()  = Console.Write "So I disposed"
    }

let Say1(cmon : IType) =
    using   <| cmon
            <| fun lol -> lol.say

Say1 St " :( " // So I disposed :(

printfn ""

let Say2(cmon : IType) (smile : string) =
    using   <| cmon
            <| fun lol -> lol.say smile

Say2 St " :) " // :) So I disposed
```

I've got two questions here.

- where exactly `St` is disposed in the first call ?
- is there syntax way to pass parameters in "fuzzy" way but don't break `IDisposable` ?

*I need it because I want to pass printf - alike parameters and I can't know it's count.*

Comment: Looking at your last few questions they seem to have a common theme.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want use printf alike syntax to log to file. And I'm trying to find elegant solution for it.

Comment: So why can't you use fprintf?

Comment: I use it but I wanted to wrap it into IDisposable object to handle `StreamWriter` as suggested to me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234364/why-i-can-not-use-disposable-objects-in-object-members but the trouble is that I need to use that PrintfArgs -> () function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispose Is called once the corresponding `SayN` is exited.

In the first case the function exits (so dispose is called) and returns a function of type `string -> ()` which is then executed and prints its result.

In the second case, the result is printed then the function exits (so Dispose is called after the string is printed to the console)

I would say that the best solution would be to Use a DU for the parameters - so you define

```
type t = |N |S of string ... //for all possible cases
```

then you just make your function take an argument of type `t`

Comment: DU for parameters? I don't fully understand. May you provide some example related example please.

Comment: So your Say becomes `let Say2 (cmon : Itype) (arg:t) = using <| cmon <| fun t -> match arg with |S(s) -> t.say s ...  //other cases here`.  Also, your syntax is a bit weird, many of the `<|` are unreqired and using `Console.Write` instead of `printf` is weird.

Comment: I used Console.Write for example and `(arg:t)` is still being one parameter. What if I want to pass 100 parameters?

Comment: Then one of your DU cases is `|Long of int * int * ...` for 100 parameters - which is a bit ugly but in that case you are better off with an array.

Comment: I mean printf style parameters alike I want to write `Log "here %s %s %s" "lot" "of" "parameters"`

Comment: I don't think there are any particularly elegant solutions for this.  The compiler actually special cases `printf` to make typechecked printf work - which I think you might have discovered already.

Comment: I tried fighting the system as well and ended up just having my logger take a single string.  `Log <| sprintf "blah %s %s" foo bar`